# add items in array to web form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an array 'sale_prices' that contains item prices.
I also have an equal amount of input forms.
I am trying to loop through each sale price and add it to the corresponding input so that input_box[1] == sale_price[1] etc...
Right now my code inputs every sale price into each input form

```
sale_prices = [
'199.99',
'199.99',
'169.99',
'217.99',
'210.99',
'227.99',
'230.99',
'257.99',
'265.99',
'271.99',
]



def add_prices():
    sale_id = '98603'
    driver.get('https://www.#######/sale-pricing.php?sale={}'.format(sale_id))
    check_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sale_checked')
    input_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "price_")]')
    for check_box in check_boxes:
        check_box.click()
    for sale_price in sale_prices:
        for input_box in input_boxes:
            input_box.send_keys(sale_price)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the for loop to this and it should work.

```
for i in range(len(sale_prices)):
    input_boxes[i].send_keys(sales_prices[i])
```

You are looping every value on input box.